# Javascript Function that changes Text Color, Hyperlink Color, and Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

[image]

Hi,

I need help with a class assignment. We were given an HTML file for a pretend business, "Castaway Vacations LLC". The first step in the assignment is to create a javascript function that changes the Text Color, Hyperlink Color, and Image when a particular link is clicked. So when the "Romantic" link is clicked, for example, the text that reads "Select Mood" will change to red, along with all other text on the page (including the other hyperlinks). Clicking this link will also change the image. One thing that's tricky about the file that our teacher sent is that there isn't a matching CSS file - I created one myself that contains the class colors, but besides that, all the other styles are inline, which I'm not used to. Here is the JSfiddle link to my code:

**UPDATE!**

I've gotten the code down for changing text color and image, but the hyperlink colors still aren't changing. You can see my attempt at changing them with the function named colorLinks in the updated javascript. Unfortunately, not only does this function not work, it's also causing the previous (good) functions to not work as well. Thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/twkm12r2/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Castaway Vacations, LLC</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bgcolor=#ffcc99 
text=#993300 link=#993300 vlink=#996633>

<br>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align="right" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
<br>
<font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<div align="center">
<table width=600>
<tr>
<td width=300 valign="top">
   <font face=arial size=3><b><i>Select Mood...</i></b></font><br><br>
   <font face=arial>
   <a id="one" href="#">Romantic</a><br><br>
   <a id="two" href="#">Adventure</a><br><br>
   <a id="three" href="#">Relaxation</a><br><br>
   <a id="four" href="#">Family</a><br><br><br>
   <br>
   <a href="#">Request A Brochure...</a>
   </font>
</td>
<td align="center"><img id="original.jpg" src="orig_main.jpg">
<br>   <i>Your Vacation Awaits!

</tr>
</center>
<script src="castaway.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</DOCTYPE>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener
('click', change_color);
document.getElementById('two').addEventListener
('click', change_color2);                                                               
document.getElementById('three').addEventListener
('click', change_color3);
document.getElementById('four').addEventListener
('click', change_color4);

function change_color(){
  document.body.style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("original.jpg").src = "rom_main.jpg";
}

function change_color2(){
  document.body.style.color = "blue";
  document.getElementById("original.jpg").src = "adv_main.jpg";
}

function change_color3(){
  document.body.style.color = "green";
  document.getElementById("original.jpg").src = "rel_main.jpg";
}

function change_color4(){
  document.body.style.color = "orange";
  document.getElementById("original.jpg").src = "fam_main.jgp";
}

colorLinks ("#00FF00");

function colorLinks (hex)

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
      if(links[i].href)
      {
          links[i].style.color = "red";  
      }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any javascript? We're not doing your homework for you. Also, that html is horrendous with missing tags, incorrect nesting of elements (div cannot be between tr/td) and `<div align="center">` with a closing tag of `</center>`. If that was from a teacher, they need to go back to school.

Comment: @Papa raise some good points. I wondered the same thing: where is the JS attemp? Lil harsh on the "horrendous" thou, he is just learning :)

Comment: It isn't his code. As stated, `We were given an HTML file for a pretend business`

Comment: I'm not asking you to do my homework. I literally have no idea where to begin because we have a shit teacher. Yes that was the HTML he gave us, I don't know if it's intentionally bad or if, like you say, it's just him. Based on the fact that I have no idea where to begin (since he won't teach us), I'm guessing it's the latter.

Comment: I will put the javascript that I started to try in a new link to an updated JSFiddle.

Comment: So he thinks he's taught you javascript? Omitting any attempts just looks like you're trying to find a easy way out. Apologies if this came over heavy handed.

Comment: No I just didn't show my attempt because I knew it was wrong. No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, for starters to change color of something you just need to do something like this

```
function change_color(){ 
 document.body.style.color = "red";  // this will change the color of the text to RED
 document.getElementById("image_to_change").src = "something.jpg"; // change img src
}
```

to use the function just add the call to the function where you want it, for example

```
  <a onClick="change_color();" href="#">Romantic</a><br><br>
```

well, its already accepted answer, but just wanted to complete it, to change the img src of, first you need to add an id for that img, for example

```
<td align="center"><img id="image_to_change"src="orig_main.jpg"><br><i>Your Vacation Awaits!
```

after you added the id, you can see how i added this line to the "change_color" function

```
document.getElementById("image_to_change").src = "***SOURCE_TO_YOUR_IMAGE***";
```

*** Working Code ***
OK, here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8ntdbek3/1/ 
i changed a few things to make it work, first, you need to understand that when you give an "ID" to something, in this case to the img (you gave the id "rom_main.jpg") the ID is what you need to use to call that element, so when you are using

```
document.getElementById("orig_main.jpg").src = "rom_main.jpg";
```

it should go

```
document.getElementById("rom_main.jpg").src = "rom_main.jpg";
```

since you gave it the id "rom_main.jpg" in this line, and the id "orig_main.jpg" does not exist!

```
 <td align="center"><img id=**"rom_main.jpg**" src="orig_main.jpg"><br><i>Your Vacation Awaits!
```

also its important to note that you can put ANY id that you want, so repeating the name of the jpg file its something that i would not recommend, since it leads to confusion.

I changed the ID to something more readable and thats it. if you still need help comment below and i'll do my best to help you.

*** EDIT to change  color ***

ok, finally i added a few lines of code to change the color of EVERY  element in your page, for each onclick i adde these lines:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");     
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
  list[i].style.color = "red";  
}
```

as you can see, i get in a list every element with the tag "a", then every element i turn it into "red" (or the color you want).

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8ntdbek3/3/

regards.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. How did you know how to do document. body.style.color?

change_color is the name of the function, so what is this string of code called?

Comment: @user3546086 document.body.style.color just modify the "css" of the body, in this case... you can use "document.getElementById("any_id").style.color" to modify the color of a specific id, of even more, not just the color, as you can see in my edit you can modify src, or any css property, for example font size, margin etc...., and i dont know how to "name" it, its just how javascript modify properties

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Even though your answer helped make sense of things, I unfortunately wasn't able to get it to work. Link to JSfiddle if you don't mind taking a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/9xsgeyno/4/

There's no way for you to see that the picture isn't changing, but you will be able to see that the text didn't change. I created four separate functions for each <a> link - was this correct?

Comment: ok, there where a few things with your code, here is the fiddle working, see edit of answer

Comment: Thanks again for your revision. The text change function is working great, but I'm still not able to get the hyperlink colors to change. I've updated my code above and there is a new link to a JSfiddle. As you'll see, the function that I tried doesn't work, and it also caused the change_color and image swap functions to not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92311/discussion-between-user3546086-and-shocklo).